# My server is compatible with TLS 1.2?

Tags: https, openssl, mac-osx-server

I just need to know if this server i compatible with TLS 1.2, through this message:

```
remote:~ Xserver$ openssl s_client -connect X:443 -tls1_2
CONNECTED(00000003)
140735304528736:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:s3_pkt.c:362:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 7 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1480093191
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Anyone?

Comment: `Verify return code: 0 (ok)` means yes...
you could also check ssllabs

Comment: this means that it supports? i will check that

Comment: you forced the connection over tls 1.2, so it's works, but there's no cert

Comment: letsencrypt my friend.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jacob! The other ssllabs is a pretty amazing tool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partially, the server support TLS 1.2 but you didn't send a cert to actually do the encryption.

Also TLS1.2 was standards in 2008.

https://www.feistyduck.com/ssl-tls-and-pki-history/

Answer (score 1):

> Protocol  : TLSv1.2
>   ...
>       Verify return code: 0 (ok)

It seems to be yes.